# Affiliations on single line with RevTeX-4.1

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, revtex, affiliation, author

I wonder if there is an easy way to get all affiliations on one line with RevTeX-4.1.

Comment: Could you add an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: @StefanPinnow, no because I do not know how to get all affiliations on one line. Perhaps you want an example where RevTeX-4.1 does NOT do what I want (i.e. puts affiliations on separate lines), but that is just the default setting, so anyone that uses RevTeX-4.1 has plenty of examples.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way.  You have to modify an internal macro.  Also it will look really ugly.  Don't do that.

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}

\makeatletter
\def\@affil@script#1#2#3#4{%
 \@ifnum{#1=\z@}{}{%
  %\par % <--- comment out
  \begingroup
   \frontmatter@affiliationfont
   \@ifnum{\c@affil<\affil@cutoff}{}{%
    \def\@thefnmark{#1}\@makefnmark
   }%
   \ignorespaces#3%
   \@if@empty{#4}{}{\frontmatter@footnote{#4}}%
   %\par % <--- comment out
  \endgroup
 }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{John Doe}
\affiliation{University of Neverland, Road to Nowhere 123, 12345 Nevercounty}
\author{Jane Smith}
\affiliation{Bogus Institute of Something, Madeup Place 654, 65432 Anywhere}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I 'solved' this myself by adding my list of affiliations as a single author with linebreaks, `\textit` and `\sciptsize`

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[superscriptaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{A Potential Solution}
\author{A. Whoever\textsuperscript{1} and B. Wohever\textsuperscript{2}\endgraf
\scriptsize\itshape \textsuperscript{1}The University of Instant
Gratification, More address \quad \textsuperscript{2}The University of Instant
Gratification, More address\\ }
\maketitle\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you show us the coding you used.

Comment: As it stands this too vague and not much help to future visitors.

Comment: Thank you.  I have added a modified version of your code to your answer.